# How can I install Ubuntu without using the Wubi installer?

Tags: windows, system-installation, wubi, live-usb

I have read a Danish book about Ubuntu. It seemed quite "easy" so I have decided that I want to erase windows 7 (actually windows 8 consumer preview) completely and install Ubuntu.

The problem is that I only could find Wubi installers on the webpage. What to do?

Comment: It appears you just did not dig very deep into the links provided on http://www.ubuntu.com/. In particular, [**this page**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) provides information on how to run or install Ubuntu from a CD or a USB stick. (This is what you could do after obtaining an install ISO image using one of the methods proposed in the answers provided so far.)

Comment: Refer to http://askubuntu.com/a/145652/54298 for more details on how to install Ubuntu with the Live CD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/22949) or (less likely in this case, as it sounds like your computer shipped with Windows 7) [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/22949)

Answer (score 5):

This should give you all the information you need

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

If you download from a torrent there should be no need to check that the download is good prior to burning.

Torrent download options can be found on the same page as the other Ubuntu download options - http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Comment: thank you for your answers but it gets more complicated! i did all of the things (burnt the cd etc.) but i have windows 8, so it cant startup by cd....

Comment: Not to sound stupid but did you insert the CD,enter the BIOS and boot from your burned CD?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to worry, just download the latest Ubuntu release from here and write it in a CD/DVD and boot with CD/DVD drive afterwards.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing different for ubuntu when it comes to installing an operating system.You follow the exact same procedure as you would do with any other OS,like Windows or Mac.

Of course you can use the wubi installer if you are unfamiliar with the installing procedures,but ubuntu will not be installed in another partition of your hard drive, just "nested" inside your already running windows/mac partition.

The ubuntu help page provides lots of useful information on how to install ubuntu:

First of all,what you have to do is download the .iso file containing ubuntu from the [related ubuntu page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).Then you can burn the .iso file into a USB drive and boot from there, which you can achieve using the cross-platform tool named [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

You may also burn the .iso in a CD, following this  [Microsoft Windows tutorial](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Burn-a-CD-or-DVD-from-an-ISO-file).

Last but not least, you can buy a CD with Ubuntu 12.04 pre-installed from the [Official Canonical Store](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I keep repeating the error - somehow when creating a boot USB disk I am getting the wrong version and no dialogue comes up for options to select 'replace windows'. I cannot seem to distinguish the correct series of links on the website to the correct download... At least I think that is my error, or is it further along in the process where I could be going wrong?

I installed using WUBI but did not realise until the restart that it was nested. Perhaps it is appropriate to note for newbs exctly what WUBI is before we download. I will now dig deep into the links to find an ISO that is not partition installed within windows.

Part of my reason for putting Ubuntu on one of my machines instead of windows is that it is now 10 years old, and post service pack 3, it is just dysfunctional. I wanted a clean install.

Anyhows Ububtu runs far slicker on the machine than windows did, I like the UI, reminds me a bit of apple 20 years ago. That is a complement btw.

Answer (score 0):

There is also Pendrive Linux.  Download the Ubuntu ISO image from the download section of Ubuntu.com and then use this guide to get the ISO image on the USB flashdrive: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/.